# Custom markers in Excel depending on data point value

Tags: excel, linechart, markers

I am kind of a newbie with Excel, so asking this question here. I have already checked some videos but the examples do not fit my need, so I am wondering if this is even possible.

I have a line chart with 10 data points, and for each data point I am currently using a built-in dot marker. The data values can go from 1 to 5, which corresponds to a net promoting score where 1 is "extremely satisfied" and 5 is "extremely satisfied": I would like to have an emoticon to represent each value, e.g. sad face for 1 and happy face for 5, and have this in a systematic way, so that every chart I generate will have these custom markers displayed depending on the value.

I would go with:

- having a separate sheet with a table containing the values and the related images (not sure if this is even possible)
- creating some sort of magic formula to link the data value to the image
- apply the magic formula to the charts

Is this approach correct? Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I hope you are looking for something like [this](https://youtu.be/oGheW733P9Q) ?